# Iso size versus Disk size

Tags: hard-drive, backup, usb-drive, disk-usage, dd

Hi guys I have a curiosity.
Some days ago I installed an ubuntu on a flash disk. Then I took an image of its ext4 and swap area via dd. However, after a while I decided that I should move this ubuntu to a hard disk instead of the flash disk. I restored my ubuntu on a hard disk via dd by using the image of the ubuntu on the flash disk. The thing is that the flash disk has a capasity of 8GB and there were only 1GB free space and the hard disk has 150GB. However, when I run the ubuntu on that hard disk, it says that there are only 1GB unused and the 99 percentage of the hard disk is used. Why ubuntu ignores the rest of the hard disk's space. Actually, it does not because it says 149GB is used, which means it is aware of the my disk space but in someway it sees the space is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you used `dd` to copy the entire flash disk to the hard drive, then you still have partitions sized appropriately to fit onto an 8GB drive.  You'll need to boot using an Ubuntu CD (instead of into the OS itself), and use the utility `gparted` to expand the partitions appropriately to fill the drive.